# Get the Intersection of Two Dictionaries with different Data Types

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have Two Dictonaries as follows

```
Dictionary<string,string> DictA=new Dictionary<string,string>();
Dictionary<int,string> DictB=new Dictionary<int,string>();
DictA.Add("A","A1");
DictA.Add("B","B1");
DictA.Add("C","C1");

DictB.Add(10,"A");
DictB.Add(20,"B");
DictB.Add(30,"K");
```

I now need to form a Third Dictonary with the Intersection of two values as follows

```
<10,A1>
<20,B1>`
```

Since K is not in first Dictionary , it will not be there in the result. 
I am pretty much sure this is doable with operations on Dictionaries or Lambda Expressions but not sure on how to achieve this.

Comment: This won't compile.  `DictB` is instantiated differently to it's declaration, and when used neither of the items in the key or value are integers.

Comment: What are the `A`, `B`, and `K` variables? They should be `int` according to your definition of `DictB`. Are you trying to match them based on the names of the variables?

Comment: Please formulate code that actually compiles and runs, and **check** that it does so, then post it.

Comment: To avoid this next time, don't type your code directly into the question box. Copy it from a working example in Visual Studio. You'll get much quicker answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that like this:

```
var result = DictB
    .Where(b => DictA.ConainsKey(b.Value))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => DictA[x.Value]);
```

This will return a new `Dictionary<int, string>` that contains entries for keys in `DictB` that have a value that exists as a key in `DictA`.

Answer (score 0):

Query expression version

```
var r = (from a in DictA
                join b in DictB on a.Key equals b.Value
                select new {b.Key, a.Value}).ToDictionary(p=>p.Key, p=>p.Value);
```